# sharekit not working on facebook

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sharekit

facebook is not working on sharekit api .. after login then access permission is ok but after will its not display any thing just gone.. i check in iphone simulator.

Please help me out.. thanks.

Comment: please some buddy answer i am very thankful ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don'y completly understand what your asking or where your having trouble, but this is how I do it:

```
-(IBAction)connectButton {
    SHKItem *item;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"put the link to the itunes store for your app here"];
    //this link is so if a person clicks the Facebook post, they will be directed to your app in the store

    NSString *postString = @"I just played a game of some game!;
    item = [SHKItem URL:url title:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"I'm playing some game! Want to play too?"];        
    item = [SHKItem URL:url title:@"Share Me!"];

    // Share the item
    [SHKFacebook shareItem:item];
}
```

sorry I had trouble formatting that.
also, make sure you import `SHKFacebook.h` in your class file.

This will open the Facebook dialog from a button within your app

Comment: Andrew Facebook has change their API they need Application ID and SHKItem never need so that a reason when popup open after login its disappear.. thats a prblem twitter and other services of SHK are running great but the facebook are still not working i tried too much .. !!

Comment: Hi I am facing same problem.Please share solutions if anybody found somethin.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Go in facebook.m class and change the authorization to NO as mention below:

```
(void)authorize:(NSArray *)permissions 
{
  self.permissions = permissions;

  [self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hey i m facing this problem also. when i logging in after autorizing app thn getting just white screen.
so i found one code in this sharekit + graph api they used. and itzz working great but big problem is that for logging in fb itz going out of app. and opening safari. so anyone hv solution for tht we can get working facebook perfactely.

i m sharing link of that code. plzz in plist file add ur fb appID.then check it.

http://www.mediafire.com/?fgescq4s2cbazfk